# В Delphi не работает update таблицы

Tags: delphi, sql-server, ado

Подключил Delphi и SQL Server. Пытаюсь обновить базу. Выдает ошибку, во вложенный:

```
qry1.SQL.Clear;
qry1.SQL.Add('UPDATE ticket SET voz_sub_som = foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 ');
qry1.SQL.Add(' and (cast(DEALDATE as date)>='+#39+StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp1.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])+#39+' and cast(DEALDATE as date)<='+#39+StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp2.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])+#39+')');
qry1.Open;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если остановить  период есть ошибка

```
qry1.SQL.Clear;
qry1.SQL.Add('UPDATE ticket SET voz_sub_som = foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 ');
//qry1.SQL.Add(' and (cast(DEALDATE as date)>='+#39+StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp1.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])+#39+' and cast(DEALDATE as date)<='+#39+StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp2.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])+#39+')');
qry1.Open;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам запрос update работает в sql server

Comment: Приведите текст запроса, который у вас отрабатывает в SQL Server

Comment: UPDATE ticket SET voz_sub_som = foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100

Comment: запрос работает в sql думаю ошибка в delphi

Comment: А как вы себе представляете, в студии должен отработать запрос из вашего кода выше - `UPDATE ticket SET voz_sub_som = foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 and .....` ?

Comment: `StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp2.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])` вы серьезно? Это же операция на гландах, через задний проход.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qry1.SQL.Clear;
qry1.SQL.Add('UPDATE ticket SET voz_sub_som = foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 ');
//qry1.SQL.Add(' and (cast(DEALDATE as date)>='+#39+StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp1.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])+#39+' and cast(DEALDATE as date)<='+#39+StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp2.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])+#39+')');
qry1.ExecSQL;
```

Вот так Сур.

Answer (score 0):

Первый фрагмент кода просто невалиден. Конечно студия выругается, что `and` некорректен. Вы же по сути выполняете:

```
UPDATE ticket SET voz_sub_som = foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 and .....
```

---

Что касается второго фрагмента - если запрос не возвращает датасета (о чем опять же говорит текст ошибки), то следует использовать не `qry1.Open`, а `qry1.ExecSQL`.